# jQueryUI buttonset style issue

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a buttonset, here's the normal one, [photo](http://s11.postimage.org/sieamntpv/buttonset2.png)

So, after applying some UI style, I get the buttons styled, but please check the next [image](http://s13.postimage.org/lx8rmiw3b/buttonset1.png)... A weird button-dot appears on the left side. (if I click on it, the buttonset activates button #3)

I have to say that this weird little button only appears using Chrome, if I browse it using IE, it's 100% fine.

The code for the buttonset is pretty simple,

**//JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#radio").buttonset();
    });
```

**//HTML**

```
<div id="radio" align="center">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" runat="server" value="BtnNextCaseClick" name="radio" checked="true"/><label for="radio1" style="width: 109px; margin-right:-.9em">Siguiente Caso</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" runat="server" value="CloseCaseAndBandeja" name="radio" /><label for="radio2" style="margin-right:-.9em">Terminar Caso y Cerrar Bandeja</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" runat="server" value="CloseBandeja" name="radio"/><label for="radio3" style="width: 109px">Cerrar Bandeja</label>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to remove that style error?

Comment: Why would you style radio buttons like that, you could just as easily use an unordered list and achieve the same results with none of the problems styled radio buttons have ?

Comment: It's how the project was done. There's more JS code firing when some of the buttons id get activated. Can't just dump it and start all over again, kind of a needed buttonset.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this

```
#radio .ui-helper-hidden-accessible { display: none; }
```

#### Explanation

I observed in my project that one part of how buttonset() works is that it sets the 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' class on the underlying radio inputs, which is then supposed to cause the radio inputs to be hidden per the style defined for 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' in the jQuery UI CSS stylesheet.

However, IMO, as evidenced by your case for Chrome, and my case for IE, it seems to me that the jQuery UI CSS style for 'ui-helper-hidden-accessible' is not sufficient enough to hide the radio input in all cases. So my answer is to add this short jQuery UI hack to your project's stylesheet and be done with it. We do want the real radio input hidden, after all, because we want buttons instead; and we do want the radio input to still be there, after all, because that is how everything stays working behind the scenes - the buttonset is just a layer for the frontend.

The hack style targets the buttonset container (this is #radio in your case) before it targets the ui-helper-hidden-accessible class in order to limit the application of the hack to just where we know it is necessary and works -- i.e. so it doesn't go breaking other parts of your site, other jQuery UI components, etc.

Note that you didn't mention your jQuery UI version, so I can't be 100% sure for your case. I developed this hack on jQuery UI 1.8.17, which defines ui-helper-hidden-accessible as

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible 
{ 
    position: absolute !important;  
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); 
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px); 
}
```